# OAuth 2 client implementation how to request for new scope?

Tags: java, android, oauth-2.0

I am implementing OAuth 2 flow on our client (Android app). The client is our app which communicates with a trusted server. There is no third party here.

When user logs in , I uses the client id and secret to get authorization code from the server and eventually I get the access token.

I have the access tokens stored in the app along with refresh token and expiry time for a particular scope say 'X'.

Now we are adding a new feature to the app but the server requires me to send scope 'Y' to access the resource for that feature from the server.

My questions are

1. Do I need to tell the server that this user needs a scope 'Y' ? If yes, How do I do it ? I just have the accesstoken & refresh token  for scope 'X'.  Does the server needs to expose a service which takes my current accesstoken and new scopes and return a new accesstoken for scope 'X' & 'Y' ? Did I get lost ?
2. On client side I assume an accesstoken should map to several scopes.

Answer (score 0):

See the spec [here](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-v2-30#section-3.3)

> The authorization and token endpoints allow the client to specify the scope of the access request using the "scope" request parameter.

`e.g server may have scope : view_my_picture delete_my_picture create_entry_in_album`

`grant_type=<e.gclient_credentials>&client_id=<yourApp>&client_secret=<secret>&scope=view_my_picture`

The server may provide all requested permissions or a modified list (for example because the user denied some permissions):

> If the issued access token scope is different from the one requested by the client, the authorization server MUST include the "scope" response parameter to inform the client of the actual scope granted.

Comment: Thank you. My Question is more on How to add a new scope or request for new scope without having the user to relogin or provide their credentials  again? Or in other words what is the standard practice in  adding / requesting additional scope to the existing accesstoken which is tied to a different scope ?